# Drag and drop screen change

Tags: android, android-fragments, drag-and-drop, multiscreen

1 - I need create two (sccrens) [fragments || view || ??] in one (Android). Botton sceen user can move up and down by drag and drop method on button.

"in screen 1 will be activity 1 and in scr. 2 will by activity 2. Together must communicating."

http://s8.postimg.org/4shq9vwpx/screen.jpg

2 - Second problem, how correctly show show ZBar (or ZXing) in Screen 1?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you please post your query clearly. hope no one understand your problem exactly.

Comment: I need create activity as image. The are two fragments: (1) and (2). In fragment (1) I need create QR reader, use ZBar or ZXing. Fragment (2) can change size to up or down pulling button in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

To implement drag and drop functionality you can read these tutorial including code examples.

- [http://www.vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html)
- [http://www.techrepublic.com](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/try-androids-useful-drag-and-drop-api/)
- [http://javapapers.com](http://javapapers.com/android/android-drag-and-drop/)

definitely you will find what you are looking for. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I'm new in android... Drag and drop is ok. I do that. But how can I implement Zbar (QR reader) inside screen (1). Thaks! ;)

Comment: check this link to read QR-http://android-sample-code.blogspot.in/2012/01/qr-code-reader-android.html

Comment: http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Comment: @Mnio you should also check the [Android stack](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=zxing)...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I do not really get what you are looking for, please improve your question and make clear what you want. From the Picture I guess you are looking for something like that: [LINK](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/01/slidingdrawer-in-android-a-simple-example/)

It's called [Sliding Drawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

Nevertheless, take your time and work through some tutorials, for example from [HERE](http://www.vogella.com/android.html) and get to know JAVA. I do recommend you to buy a Book in your mother tongue!